# Wrong canonicalization by Google

Tags: google, search-engines, canonical-url

I had 2 pages with mostly same text and the difference being in Flash and cities names. So, Google started to think that those were copies of the same page and to index only the most popular of them. So I changed texts. No result. I used this http://www.google.com/addurl/ and Google still crawled only the most popular page. What do I have to do to convince Google that those are different pages? So far only changing urls comes to my mind.

Answer (score 2):

If each page contains more duplicate content then original content you're probably going to have a hard time with Google weeding out most of your pages as low quality. As with almost everything related to Google, you're best bet is to get high quality links to your web pages. The more quality links each page has, the higher the quality of the page in Google's eyes.

Another option is to find a way to add more unique content to each page.